# Using Flask_sqlAlchemy Cross database engine in Pandas.read_sql

Tags: pandas, flask-sqlalchemy, model-binding

Dears,

I would like to execute sql queries and get the results in pandas DF. 
DB is sqlite3, using flask_sqlalchemy

I got 3 databases which are binds to the sqlalchemy app, models are created using the bind keyword. Not issue here, tables are well created in each database file.

However, assuming I've got 3 DBs (DB1, DB2, DB3) and one table in each DB (T1, T2,, T3)

the default DB is DB1, DB2 and DB3 are binds of DB1

I want to execute this code (sql query is stupid, this is just for example):

```
    sql = "select T2.ID, sum(T3.val) as val
    FROM T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
    GROUP BY T2.ID"

    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

The issue here is `con...`

I have seen many examples to switch from one engine to another using `con = db.get_engine(bind='***')`

but this assumes that T2 and T3 are in the same database, which is not the case

here I got 2 tables in 2 databases, so how can I set the connection to pandas ?

Thks

NB : in the real system some databases have hundreds of millions lines, so using SQL and then pandas is the most efficient way in terms of performances, rather than using the sqlalchemy objects like query, filter, ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in sqlite, but in Mysql or Postgresql you could reach tables accross databases/schemas by specifying the name of the database in you query. 
Try :

```
sql = "select T2.ID, sum(T3.val) as val
       FROM DB2.T2 
       INNER JOIN DB3.T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
       GROUP BY T2.ID"
```

Comment: hi, the point is that the tables are in different databases, whatever it is sqlite or another DB engine. In fact, the live tables are in ORACLE, but I'm trying to develop the BE and FE using sqlite on testing data...

Comment: Ah, when you talk about databases, you mean SGBD?

Comment: Ah ok, so you can't do join accross different sgbd with one sql query. The only way for you is to load data from table1 and table2 with two sql queries and two engine then merge in pandas.

Comment: got it, thks barthelemy